# Linear map with properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Give two vectors $v_1=(a,b,c)$ and $v_2=(d,e,f)$ in $\mathbb R^3$, how two explicitly find a linear function $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that:

1. $f(v_i)$ belongs to the plane XY (for $i=1,2$);
2. $f(v_i)$ and $v_i$ have the same norm (for $i=1,2$);
3. The angle between $f(v_1)$ and $f(v_2)$ is equal to the angle between $v_1$ and $v_2$;
4. $f(v_1\times v_2)=(0,0,1)$   ??

I can see that we are looking at the plane XY with a copy of these two given vectors, but I have not found the explicit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I buy the 'only linear function' part!

Let $v_3 = v_1 \times v_2$, we must have $v_3\neq 0$ by 3., hence
$v_1,v_2,v_3$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

To define a linear function, it is sufficient to define it on a basis.

The $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are the unit vectors in the $x,y,z$ directions.

Let $\alpha = {\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle \over \|v_1\| \|v_2\|}$.

Define $f(v_1) = \|v_1\|e_1, f(v_2) = \|v_2\|(\alpha e_1+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2} e_2), f(v_3) = e_3$. It is clear that
this satisfies 1-3.

We could also define
$f(v_1) = -\|v_1\|e_1, f(v_2) = -\|v_2\|(\alpha e_1+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2} e_2), f(v_3) = e_3$. It is clear that
this also satisfies 1-3.

In fact there are an uncountable number of different $f$ satisfying the
conditions :-).